# iOS Voice Over rotor notifications?

Tags: ios, keyboard, notifications, voiceover, rotor

One of the Voice Over rotor options is **typing mode**.
When the typing mode is **standard**, you touch a key to hear what the key does and you have to double tap it to actually use it.
When the typing mode is **touch typing**, the keyboard behaves almost as if Voice Over wasn't on.

Is there a way to know when the "typing mode" changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked Apple about this and there is no way of knowing when the rotor options are changing.